# button different each box css keep same alignment

Tags: html, css

is their anyway on this page here

http://www.cmsni.net/portfollio/#!prettyPhoto

to keep the reading button at the same hight at all as it looks a bit of a mess all over the place at the mo thanks for any help

Comment: Please read the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)** for directions on how to ask a question. This isn't the proper format for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink the layout of the information to eliminate the jagged content, here is one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/65UpU/

HTML

```
<div class="tbl">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs51/200H/f/2009/264/c/8/Cutie_Kitten_by_Littlemeteor.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs51/200H/f/2009/264/c/8/Cutie_Kitten_by_Littlemeteor.jpg" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs51/200H/f/2009/264/c/8/Cutie_Kitten_by_Littlemeteor.jpg" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs51/200H/f/2009/264/c/8/Cutie_Kitten_by_Littlemeteor.jpg" />           
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>This is a header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>This is a jagged header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>This is even more of a jagged header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Wow, I can't beleive how this is even more of a jagged header</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictum libero aliquet non ac cras taciti, pede non lorem, ut nulla mauris tincidunt felis, id eleifend, netus ligula lobortis vestibulum interdum ipsam id
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictum libero aliquet non ac cras taciti, pede non lorem, ut nulla mauris tincidunt felis, id eleifend, netus ligula lobortis vestibulum interdum ipsam id. Ad gravida et hac sociosqu, libero in lacus in laoreet ac enim. Quam enim, venenatis pellentesque integer consequat mauris leo nibh, et nec ac libero odio lorem tristique. Ipsum pharetra nec nunc
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictum libero aliquet non ac cras taciti, pede non lorem, ut nulla mauris tincidunt felis, id eleifend, netus ligula lobortis vestibulum interdum ipsam id. Ad gravida et hac sociosqu, libero in lacus in laoreet ac enim. Quam enim, venenatis pellentesque integer consequat mauris leo nibh, et nec ac libero odio lorem tristique. Ipsum pharetra nec nunc ullamco, massa auctor adipiscing elit, etiam interdum nisl. Maecenas congue mauris dolor condimentum.
        </div>
        <div class="col">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictum libero aliquet non ac cras taciti, pede non lorem, ut nulla mauris tincidunt felis, id eleifend, netus ligula lobortis vestibulum interdum ipsam id. Ad gravida et hac sociosqu, libero in lacus in laoreet ac enim. Quam enim, venenatis pellentesque integer consequat mauris leo nibh, et nec ac libero odio lorem tristique. Ipsum pharetra nec nunc ullamco, massa auctor adipiscing elit, etiam interdum nisl. Maecenas congue mauris dolor condimentum.
Proin convallis placerat est sed nullam consectetuer, eget ullamcorper arcu quam dignissim suscipit nunc. Nulla arcu ipsum tempor sit ut egestas, vitae fermentum praesent, nunc eu quam, eget porta dui et nunc. Cursus congue quam commodo, donec elit varius nullam amet nunc            
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="row_read_more">
        <div class="col">
            READ MORE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            READ MORE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            READ MORE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            READ MORE
        </div>
    </div>    


</div>
```

CSS

```
.tbl { width:1000px; }
.row { overflow:hidden;}
.row_read_more{ margin:20px 0 0 0; }
.col { width:230px; margin:0 20px 0 0; float:left; }
.col:last-child { margin:0; }
```

Comment: +1 that's the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I get in mind right now would be setting the divs to a fixed `height` and `position` the button `absolute` to the bottom. But I guess, fixing the height is not what you want.